# How to reload Datatable using Ajax when checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I want to be able to reload my Datatable once my checkbox is clicked , provided below is my attempted code but I continue to get error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null not really sure how to handle this error. I have provided both the javascript and the view in my MVC application please let me know if you need more details.

***.js***

```
function ReloadTable()
{


    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table =  $('#DashboardTable').DataTable({

            "processing": true, // for show progress bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process server side
            "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
            //"pageLength": 5,


            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Chargeback/Index",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
            { "data": "ChargebackCode" },
            { "data": "StatusName" },
            { "data": "BusinessUnitName" },
            { "data": "InvoiceCode" },
            { "data": "OrderCode" },
            { "data": "PickTicketCode" },
            { "data": "CustomerPo" },
            { "data": "AssignedDepartment" },
            { "data": "DivisionName" },
            { "data": "Customer" },
            { "data": "WarehouseName" },
            { "data": "Coordinator" },
            { "data": "ChargebackDate" },
            { "data": "ModDate" },
            { "data": "ChargebackDeadline" },
            { "data": "ChargebackCloseDate" },
            { "data": " DaysOpen" },
            { "data": "ChargebackAmount" },
            { "data": "ChargebackBalance" },
            { "data": "FaultName" },
            { "data": "ResponsibleName" }
            ]

        });
        table.ajax.reload();
    });

}
```

***view:***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Chargeback"))
{
   <label id = "Include" > @Html.CheckBox("IncludeClosed", (bool)ViewBag.IncludeClosed, new { onChange = "ReloadTable()" }) Include Closed</label>

<table id="DashboardTable" class="table table-striped" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Business</th>
            <th>Invoice</th>
            <th>Order</th>
            <th>Pick Tickets</th>
            <th>Customer PO</th>
            <th>Assigned</th>
            <th>Division</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Warehouse</th>
            <th>Coordinator</th>
            <th>Open Date</th>
            <th>Last Activity</th>
            <th>Deadline</th>
            <th>Closed Date</th>
            <th>Days Open</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Balance</th>
            <th>Fault</th>
            <th>Responsible</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            var chargebackDeadline = item.ChargebackDeadline == null ? "" : ((DateTime)item.ChargebackDeadline).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            var chargebackCloseDateAsString = item.ChargebackCloseDate == null ? "" : ((DateTime)item.ChargebackCloseDate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(item.ChargebackCode, "Details", "Chargeback", new { id = item.Id }, null)</td>
                <td>@item.StatusName</td>
                <td>@item.BusinessUnitName</td>
                <td>@item.InvoiceCode</td>
                <td>@item.OrderCode</td>
                <td>@item.PickTicketCode</td>
                <td>@item.CustomerPo</td>
                <td>@item.AssignedDepartment</td>
                <td>@item.DivisionName</td>
                <td>@item.Customer</td>
                <td>@item.WarehouseName</td>
                <td>@item.Coordinator</td>
                <td>@item.ChargebackDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                <td>@item.ModDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
                <td>@chargebackDeadline</td>
                <td>@chargebackCloseDateAsString</td>
                <td>@item.DaysOpen</td>
                <td>$@item.ChargebackAmount</td>
                <td>$@item.ChargebackBalance</td>
                <td>@item.FaultName</td>
                <td>@item.ResponsibleName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have any stacktrace information?

Comment: @JeroenHeier are you referring to this:
(anonymous) @ Refresh.js:44

fire @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3062

add @ jquery-1.10.2.js:3108

ready @ jquery-1.10.2.js:285

ReloadTable @ Refresh.js:5

onchange @ Index:142

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean. So what is the code on Refresh.js, line 44? Add a breakpoint and try to debug.

Comment: @JeroenHeier This is looking at my console.Trace I added in me .js file, should I go through each stack trace and look at each of them individually?

Comment: You cannot set a property on a null object. You need to add that code part to your question so that we can understand what you are doing. Can you comment out that code in order to see if this solves your problem?

Comment: @JeroenHeier which code are you asking me to comment out exactly , and which code part are you asking me to add to my question ?
Are you referring to  the console.Trace() , if so this code isn't altering anything its just getting my stack trace